# When remoting to PC from Mac, Tab not working and Shift+Space works instead of normal Space

Tags: keyboard, imac, remote-desktop, pc

As the title states, whilst using Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection from my Mac to office PC I have encountered the following problems:

1. <kbd>Tab</kbd> key not doing anything
2. <kbd>Space</kbd> not working, instead only <kbd>Shift</kbd>+Space works for some reason (an issue when typing anything)

All other keys are working normally and everything else works normally except these 2 keys. I have tried **Razor BlackWidow v3** and **Magic Keyboard** (that came with my iMac M1).
The same issues occur for both keyboards while I'm working on my remote PC from my iMac.

**EDIT**: Ok, it appears that Spacebar triggers Left Mouse Button

Comment: Check your accessibility preferences to make sure Full Keyboard Access is turned OFF

Comment: Thank you! It appears that did the trick :)

Answer (score 3):

Space not working often means that you have Full Keyboard Access (part of Accessibility Preferences) turned on by mistake.

Comment: you are a real life saver! I was about to lose my mind for real